# convergence of neural network back propagation

Tags: matlab, neural-network, mse

I had built a neural network in the weights update step the mean error square go directly to 0 for example

```
mean error square 1 =  1.2
mean error square 2 = 0 
mean error square 3 = 0 
mean error square 4 = 0 
mean error square 5 = 0 
mean error square 6 = 0 ....................
```

I don't know what is the problem
the size of my neural network is: input = 324 * 540 target = 10 * 540

when I try with an other data with this size input = 81* 540 target = 10 * 540

it works

maybe the problem in the learning rate?

Comment: If you want help, you need to at least provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I dont understand your question. Could you please provide a more clear description.